# Find and replace a special unicode character

Tags: excel, unicode, vba

I have a particular column that has multiple occurrences in multiple rows of a special character.  It's the "Response" character.  It's a capital R with a slash through it.  It's represented as Unistring 211F.  It can also be represented in HTML as &#8479.

I'd like to use VBA to search for the "Response" character and replace it with "Response" and the line feed ASC(10).

How can I search and replace this special character?

Comment: There are many examples of VBA Find & Replace on `xlPart` but you will want to search for `what:=ChrW(8479)` and replace with `replacement:="Replace" & Chr(10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to search for `what:=ChrW(8479)` and replace with `replacement:="Replace" & Chr(10)`.

This quick code will make your Unichar-to-Text replacement across the active worksheet.

```
Sub replace_Response()
    Dim fnd As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Replace what:=ChrW(8479), replacement:="Response" & Chr(10), lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

The range of replacements can be pared down to a column, row or any selected group of cells.