# Finding characters with unicode "long stroke overlay" applied in excel

Tags: excel, unicode, replace

I've imported a file from text into excel that has a bunch of values struck out using unicode's long stroke overlay. I need to find and replace them all with zero. What function can I use to find these characters?

Comment: I think you could adapt this approach to either replace or with Find Next , to find each occurence, [Find and replace a special unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946639/find-and-replace-a-special-unicode-character) with i am guessing  ChrW(0336)

Comment: or Regex way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024107/excel-vba-remove-unicode-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946639/find-and-replace-a-special-unicode-character)'s answer would the following work?

```
Sub ReplaceLongStrongOverlay()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Replace what:=ChrW(822), replacement:="0", lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could set up a [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) pattern such as "[^\u0336]" , you might need to fiddle with this a bit, and with `regEx.Global` set to `True` do a find and replace.